# Number of Solutions to a Linear Equation Mod N

Tags: linear-algebra, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Is there a formula for the number of solutions to
$$a_1x_1+\dots+a_nx_n \equiv 0 \mod{N}$$
such that $(x_i,N)=1$ in terms of the coefficients $a_1,\dots,a_n$?

Clearly, by Chinese Remainder Theorem, we need only consider when $N$ is a prime power. Further, if $N=p$ is a prime, then this is easily to be $(p-1)^{n-1}$, and we can view it as hyper surface of the vector space $(\mathbb{F}_p)^n$. But, if $N=p^m$, $m\not=1$, then we can no longer use vector space theory to solve this.

If $n=2$, then we can solve it in the following way
$$ax_1+bx_2 \equiv 0 \mod{p^m}$$
has a solution if and only if $v_p(a)=v_p(b) = e$. Therefore we can write $a=p^ea'$ and $b=p^eb'$, where $(a',p)=(b',p)=1$. Therefore, it simplifies down to
$$a'x_1+b'x_2 \equiv 0 \mod{p^{m-e}}$$
and we get $(p-1)p^{m+e-1}$ solutions as $x_1$ can be anything coprime to $p^m$, and so has $(p-1)p^{m-1}$ choices, but then this fixes what $x_2$ can be mod $p^{m-e}$, thus giving $x_2$ $p^e$ choices.

However, I have been having difficulty seeing how to extend this to the case where we have $n$ variables. Is the answer to this problem know? What conditions on the $v_p(a_i)$ do we need to have a solution?